# How do I quote nonconsecutive sentences from a lengthy quote?

Tags: punctuation

I am writing a book compiling multiple quotes from various authors.  On occasion I do not want to use all of the quote; maybe 2 or 3 lines at the beginning; one in the middle; one in the end. Do I need to call that out by "... ??

Comment: If I understand you correctly then yes, as you say, you can use ellipsis (...). I suggest you give an actual example together with its original text(s). That way we can see if you are using it correctly.  It doesn't have to be from your book -- any passage(s) will do.

Comment: Yes, you should probably use ellipsis.

Comment: There's nothing odd about using an ellipsis to indicate an omission. If your quoted passage already includes one, of course, then that poses its own difficulties [for which there is a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232240/nested-quotation-with-ellipsis).

Answer (score 2):

An ellipsis of three dots (. . .) is routinely used to indicate an omission within a sentence or paragraph. When entire sentences are omitted from a quote, a four dot ellipsis (. . . .) is usually used, and it is usually put on a separate line from both the preceding and following sections of the quote.

[Note: This is an observation. I am still searching for an authority for this proposition.]